# How can I find what class type is expected for a method's property/properties?

Tags: php, reflection, type-hinting

I need to see what class type is being expected (type-hinted) for a method property.

```
<?php

class Foo {}

class Bar {
    public function do(Foo $foo_instance) {}
}

$bar = new Bar();
$some_instance = new ??();
$bar->do($some_instance);

?>
```

I *think* this is something available in the [Reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), but I have yet to find anything that spits out `'Foo'` as my type-hint for `Bar::do`. Any ideas?

### Context

I want to do something like:

```
<?php
...
if ( myMethodExpects($class, $method, 'Foo') ) {
    $some_instance = new Foo();
} elseif ( myMethodExpects($class, $method, 'Baz') {
    $some_instance = new Baz();
} elseif ( myMethodHasNoTypeHint($class, $method) ) {
    $some_instance = 'just a string';
}
...
?>
```

Comment: Does type hinting `Foo $foo_instance` in your method `do` prevents from being able to execute no matter the class?

Comment: What what is worth, you might be interested in [Design Strategy Pattern](https://phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html).

Comment: @Anwar awesome. I have some downtime between jobs and trying to level up my PHP skillz by building various app components.

Comment: And yeah, PHP will throw an exception if I put in the wrong instance or type of data. I want to do something like "if method expects some model instance, give it that, otherwise just pass the `(int)$id` or whatever"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, asked Google the right questions.

I was looking for [ReflectionParameter::getClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getclass.php). Used like so:

```
<?php

class Foo {
   public function do(Bar $bar, Baz $baz, $foo='') {}
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'do');
$method_params = $method->getParameters();
foreach ( $method_params as $param ) {
    var_dump($param->getClass());
}

?>

/* RETURNS
-> object(ReflectionClass)[6]
  public 'name' => string 'Bar' (length=3)
-> object(ReflectionClass)[6]
  public 'name' => string 'Baz' (length=4)
-> null
*/
```

This can also be used on `ReflectionFunction`:

```
$function_params = (new ReflectionFunction('func_name')->getParameters();
```